# Hide row if field is N/A or empty

Tags: php

I have a question regarding hiding empty rows in my table.

I want to hide an entire row in the case a field says N/A which means the field is empty.

Example:
[image: test scores table]

In the event that the field is empty or N/A, I want to hide the entire row. I will also welcome javascript solutions.

```
<tbody style="
    white-space: nowrap;
">
   <?php
        foreach($student_subject_list AS $SSL)
        {
            $subject_name = $SSL["name"];
         
            if(in_array($subject_name, array_keys($result)))
            {
                
                $total_score = 0; 
                $avg = count($result[$subject_name]); 
                $test_results = "";
                $i = 1;
                
               foreach($result[$subject_name] AS $SN)
                { 
                    if($i == 1)
                    {
                         $ie = "1<sup>st</sup>";
                    }
                    elseif($i == 2)
                    {
                        $ie = "<br>2<sup>nd</sup>";
                    }
                    elseif($i == 3)
                    {
                        $ie =  "<br>3<sup>rd</sup>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $ie =  "<br>4<sup>th</sup>";
                    }
                    
                    $test_results .= "$ie Test: $SN ";
                    $total_score  += $SN;
                    $avg_score = $total_score/$avg;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $total_score = $test_results = "N/A";
            }
 ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;white-space: nowrap;height:30px;"><?=$subject_name?></td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?=$test_results?></td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?=$avg_score?></td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;"><?=$remark?></td>
                        </tr>      
            
    <?php     
        }
    ?>                                
</tbody>
```

Comment: Sounds fine. What's your question about this? Why not simply skip the output when your condition is met?

Answer (score 0):

Could you make the html where you create the row conditional on $test_results NOT being equal to "N/A"? Something like this:

```
<?php if(!$test_results === "N/A"){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td> etc etc
    <td> etc etc
    <td> etc etc
    <td> etc etc
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This hides the test 1 column but I want to hide the rows that has 'N/A'

Comment: @MamaJardel I don't fully understand your code but surely my suggestion would not remove a column. It would remove a row because it removes a <tr> element. I have edited my answer to include all the <td> elements inside the <tr>.

Comment: ok, This removed the entire row. I'm left with only the headers (th)